# How to populate a form list with buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript

I made a script that, when you press one button(`accessories`) the selection(`mylist`) populates with one array(`accessoryData`), and when you hit the other button(`weapons`) the other array(`weaponData`) populates the selection. However, in the current state of the code the second button press is not re-populating the selection. What is wrong here?

Also if there is a more efficient way to do this, that might be helpful.

[Full code](http://jsfiddle.net/StealingMana/WKNYn/2/)

```
function runList(form, test) {
    var html = "";
    var x;
    dataType(test);
    while (x < dataType.length) {
        html += "<option>" + dataType[x];
        x++;
    }
    document.getElementById("mylist").innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: Are you constrained to just Javascript? I would suggest using the jQuery library.

Comment: I have never used jQuery. How much would it take to be able to implement it into what I already have?

Comment: It's actually much easier than bare javascript. Here's a quick implementation based off what I saw you trying to do, in jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/u4fcz/. If you have any questions I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Do you know how to code the equivalent in JavaScript? I don't understand the syntax. But that is the exact result I'm looking for.

Comment: What are those variables you're passing to the function? Also, you could rewrite that while loop with a for loop: `for(var i = 0; i < dataType.length; i++)` If you really want to write some cool JS then I would also suggest sitting down and learning jQuery. It takes a bit to get used to but it makes your life so much easier in the long run :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to make a `<select>` element ie the drop down menu, but proper markup is:

```
<select id="myList">
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="n">Option n</option>
</select>
```

You forgot to close the `<option>` tag with `innerHTML` property.

Using native ***JS*** methods:

```
//create the select element
var select = document.create('select');
//or use getElementById if it's already there

//Assuming your datatype is an Array of string
var opt;
for(var i=0; i<datatype.length; i++){
  //create the option element
  opt = document.create('option');
  opt.textContent = datatype[i]; //innerText works too
  //set the value attribute
  opt.setAttribute('value',i+1); //+1 or else it would start from 0
  //add the option to the select element
  select.appendChild(opt);
  //conversely use removeChild to remove
}

//at last add it to the DOM if you didn't fetch it from the DOM.
```